# Function events happen without calling the function

Tags: javascript

I have this function called `arie1()` that should do a bunch of stuff when I press a button with `id="calculeaza"`. The `<h1>` element is hidden by default on page loade and it should be visible only after I press the button "calculeaza" that calls the function `arie1()`. But as soon as I select option 1 in the `select` element `h1` appears. What did I do wrong?

```js
function arie1() {
  var lungC = parseFloat(document.getElementById('lungC').value);
  var latC = parseFloat(document.getElementById('latC').value);
  var hC = parseFloat(document.getElementById('hC').value);
  var hBaza = parseFloat(document.getElementById('hTotal').value);
  var latBaza = parseFloat(document.getElementById('latBaza').value);
  var arie1 = 2 * lungC * latC + 2 * lungC * hTotal + 2 * latBaza * (hC + hTotal) + 2 * 0.5 * lungC + 0.5 * latBaza + 5; //se vor lua 5m2 de rezerva si se va mentiona pe site sa se mai adauge o marja de eroare
  document.getElementById('mpv').innerHTML = arie1;
  document.getElementById('mp').style.display = 'block';
}

function arie2() {
  var lungC = parseFloat(document.getElementById('lungC').value);
  var latC = parseFloat(document.getElementById('latC').value);
  var hC = parseFloat(document.getElementById('hC').value);
  var hBaza = parseFloat(document.getElementById('hTotal').value);
  var latBaza = parseFloat(document.getElementById('latBaza').value);
  var arie2 = lungC * latC + 2 * lungC * hTotal + 2 * latBaza * (hC + hTotal) + 2 * 0.5 * lungC + 0.5 * latBaza + 5; //se vor lua 5m2 de rezerva si se va mentiona pe site sa se mai adauge o marja de eroare
  document.getElementById('mpv').innerHTML = arie2;
  document.getElementById('mp').style.display = 'block';
}

function switcherForma() {
  switch (parseInt(document.getElementById('select-forma').value)) {
    case 1:
      document.getElementById('f1').style.color = "red";
      document.getElementById('calculeaza').click = arie1();
      break;
    case 2:
      break;
    case 3:
      break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to this line:

```
document.getElementById('calculeaza').click = arie1();
```

You are *calling* `arie1()` when the page loads and assigning its response value to the `click` property of the Element object. You instead need to work with the *reference* to the function.

Also note that you do not add `click` event handlers in this manner. Use `addEventListener()` instead, providin the reference to your `arie1()` function. Try this:

```
function switcherForma() {
  switch (parseInt(document.getElementById('select-forma').value, 10)) {
    case 1:
      document.getElementById('f1').style.color = "red";
      document.getElementById('calculeaza').addEventListener('click', arie1);
      break;
    case 2:
      break;
    case 3:
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer! How can I work with the ref to my function? I am new to this language and only playing with it. Thank you! Also, should't arie1 be called like `arie1()` in the event listener?

Comment: There's an example in the answer

Comment: Why is there a `10` in the switch?

Comment: My bad, it should be in the `parseInt()`. It's the radix, see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) for more info

Comment: Why do I get a NaN where the value `arie1` should be? :(

Comment: Possibly because there was an error in my original question. I have edited to fix it. Refresh the page and double check you're using my corrected answer.

Comment: In which case one of the values within the `arie1()` function you're attempting to process are not valid for parsing. I'd suggest logging the values first, or if you still have issues, start a new question including all HTML in a working example snippet.

Comment: The user selects an option from the dropdown and the completes the fields that I get the values from. Where would be a good place to declare my variables?